# Controller dispatch error in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am returning Json response from zend controller.

This is my code

**Controller Code**

```
public function get()
{

    $result = //calling other function and getting response in array

    print("value in controller before calling toJsonModel");
    print_r($result);
    $temp = $this->toJsonModel($result);
    var_dump($temp);

    return $temp;
}
```

**toJsonModel** function

```
public function toJsonModel($data = array())
{   
    $data['requestId'] = $this->getHeader('RequestId');
    print("Value just before returning to controller");
    print_r($data);
    return new JsonModel($data);
}
```

**Response**

[image]

First and second print displays correct values. But after getting values from toJsonModel when I try to displays wrong values and adds some other values like "captureTo", "terminate" and "children" as protected.

I don't know why it's giving me wrong message.

Can any one guide me to right path and tell me what the problem is ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I am adding new screenshot to display full message.

**ERROR** :

> {"name":"Email Not Found","message":"No account found with this email
>   address.","code":404,"requestId":"12","reason":"error-controller-cannot-dispatch","display_exceptions":true,"controller":"RSMobile\Controller\ForgotPassword","controller_class":null}

[image]

Comment: What exactly is wrong?

Comment: I am getting "dispatch error". see the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this problem.

I was throwing some error from controller whenever there is a problem. I used to throw 404 when email not found. That was causing this error.

At first i thought that this is a problem related to JSON model. But thanks to @Bilal who helped me in figuring out the problem.

When I throw 404 from controller it by default appends all these data at the end. But when i throw any error other than 404, it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this solved it for me too. Just wanted to say that this is the stupidest feature. I shake my fist at you ZF2!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are returning an object of `JsonModel` from method `toJsonModel`.

```
return new JsonModel($data);
```

So, every object has some properties that you can use to manipulate data. See the docs of `Zend\View\Model\JsonModel` [here](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.View.Model.JsonModel.html)

So actually the values are not wrong but there is a way to access properties of an object.

**Update**

Attaching dispatch event

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    // some stuff
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach("dispatch", function($e) {
        echo "Dispatch!";
    });
    // some stuff
}
```

Comment: I don't want to it to be added in this. By the way if I use same function in different controller it works fine and not adding this data to object.

Comment: Because i want to return it as a API response and it should not be added in this.

Comment: @BSThakrar you're only seeing that data because you're dumping the `JsonModel`. Drop all the `print`, `print_r` and `var_dump` statements and you'll get just the json string rendered instead.

Comment: But it also displays "error controller cannot dispatch" see the last line of screenshot. what could be the reason behind this ?

Comment: I dont know how you are using it. [You can use](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.json.basics.html) `Zend\Json\Json::encode()` and `Zend\Json\Json::decode()`. There is a difference between `Zend\View\Model\JsonModel` and `Zend\Json`. If you have created a model that will manipulate only `JSON`, then you have to use that object otherwise use `Zend\Json'.

Comment: I am using this Zend\View\Model\JsonModel. I don't need to decode because i am using advance rest api client and it directly display message in json. You can see how i am creating jsonModel object in my question. See toJsonModel().

Comment: @BSThrakar The last line of the screenshot showing your error message is missing. It might help if you included that in the TEXT of your question instead of relying on a screenshot.

Comment: Then just do `$temp->serialize();` in your action.

Comment: See I added screenshot displaying full message. see if you can help me after seeing that.

Comment: [This might help you.](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/returning-json-errors-in-a-zf2-application/)

Comment: Thanks. But I have looked at this before. it's when you face this problem from onBootStrap(). because there we don't have a listener so we need to attach a listener to this. But in controller listener should not be a problem.

Comment: I didn't understand. You mean Dispatch event?

Comment: Why you don't have event listener? See updated answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47627/discussion-between-bsthakrar-and-bilal)